# Координаты границ стран и регионов для отрисовки на canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть пример карты на canvas: http://tomsgroup.ru/ru/projects/
Скрипт ее отрисовки находится в файле http://tomsgroup.ru/tpl/default/js/tpl.js
Все регионы хранятся в виде объектов с координатами, по которым затем и происходит отрисовка.

Координаты следующего вида: 
points: [[581,404],[580,396],[583,392]]

Вопрос: где взять подобного вида координаты любой страны или региона для такой же отрисовки? Есть разные сервисы типа GADM, но там  везде координаты предоставляются в виде широты и долготы,что не подходит для простой проекции их на x/y систему координат на canvas. Возможно, где-то можно сконвертировать широту и долготу в координаты x/y, или же есть какой-то сервис, где это можно взять сразу без проблем?

Comment: есть не одна библиотека, которая может это посчитать из широты и долготы, например d3.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так это можно сделать при помощи d3.js и модуля по работе с проекциями - d3.geo

```js
let rnd = n => Math.floor(Math.random()*n);

let projection = d3.geoMercator()
                   .rotate([-154, 0])
                   .scale(190)
                   .center([0, 63])

let path = d3.geoPath()
             .projection(projection)

let ctx1 = canvas(true);
let ctx2 = canvas(false);
let tooltip = d3.select('body')                         
               .append('div')
               .style('position', 'absolute')
              .style('pointer-events', 'none')
let features, pickingBuffer, mouseover, map, pickingMap = {};

let canv = document.querySelector('canvas');
canv.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
     if (!pickingBuffer) 
       return
     let prev = mouseover;
     let offset = (e.layerY*600+e.layerX)*4;
     let r = pickingBuffer[offset];
     let g = pickingBuffer[offset+1];
     let b = pickingBuffer[offset+2];
     mouseover = pickingMap[`rgb(${r},${g},${b})`];
     tooltip.style('top', e.offsetY + canv.offsetTop + 'px')
            .style('left', 15 + e.offsetX + canv.offsetLeft + 'px')
            .html(mouseover?mouseover.properties.name:'')  
     if (prev === mouseover) 
       return;
     ctx1.putImageData(map, 0, 0);
     mouseover && fill(ctx1, mouseover, 'red');
});

d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/russia.geojson").then(json => {
    features = json.features;
    features.forEach((feature, i) => {
        feature.color = `hsl(${i*69.5},65%,65%)`;
        while (!feature.pick || pickingMap[feature.pick])
          feature.pick = `rgb(${rnd(255)},${rnd(255)},${rnd(255)})`;
        pickingMap[feature.pick] = feature;
        fill(ctx1, feature, feature.color);
        fill(ctx2, feature, feature.pick);
    });
    pickingBuffer = ctx2.getImageData(0,0,600,400).data;
    map = ctx1.getImageData(0,0,600,400);
});

function canvas(visible) {
    let canvas = d3.select('body')                         
               .append('canvas')
               .attr('height', 400)
               .attr('width', 600)
               .node();
    !visible && canvas.remove();
    return canvas.getContext('2d')
}

function fill(c, feature, color) {
    c.fillStyle = color;
    c.beginPath();
    path.context(c)(feature);
    c.fill();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```